# Dynamic Grid submit with values in Extjs to java

Tags: java, spring, extjs

I am going to develop such functionality that submit grid data to java

1) i have 6 radio buttons and on click on radio buttons Grid is loaded with different no of column in each grid (Number of columns are different in each Grid)

2)i want to submit selected grid data and process for the further process

any one have idea how to achieve this please help me thanks in advance.

Mayur

Answer (score 0):

You should read the documentation, especially the examples:

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/example/writer/writer.html